# NodeJS Database Content not updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, content-management-system

I am hoping to get some help on building a portfolio website on nodeJS with a tutorial on Turbo360. ( to learn NodeJS) The Turbo CMS is not updating with the right information once I try to pull down the project locally, with both sides using the MVC architecture.

I am trying to modify the tutorial, https://www.turbo360.co/tutorial/portfolio-site-with-node-js-&-express , where information in the database should be updated thru the turbo GUI, loading in the CMS images there, reducing projects to 2, not six. However the default six are showing up. The link to my website can be found here:
https://my-portfolio-clone-axsu2z.turbo360-vertex.com/  with the two arrowed photos should be the only ones showing up.
[image]

Any help would be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Can you extrapolate the part of code or post the repo with your code?

Comment: I was just able to post to my github, found here :  https://github.com/mikeypskazyG/example-site